# session id is not set in request header while requesting a domain url

Tags: visualforce, community, session, session-id

I have url https://es-portal.gavi.org/sdgavi--uat/sdcs101/ in custom settings while redirecting to the url session id is not set in the cookie for that it always redirecting to login page..From request header i got that session id is not set .But as expected salesforce should set the sid in cookie as we don't have control on request header.

[image]

Can anyone please suggest why sid or session is not set?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.